# Python, Pandas Split dataframes into columns by a delimiter (:) to existing columns (Data Cleaning)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
23  Don Cheadle 2885.4  34  84.9    Avengers: Age of Ultron 459 Don Cheadle YEs
24  Ben Stiller:2827.0:37:76.4:Meet the Fockers:27...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I need something like

```
23  Don Cheadle 2885.4  34  84.9    Avengers: Age of Ultron 459 Don Cheadle YEs
24  Ben Stiller 2827.0  37  76.4    Meet the Fockers    279.3   Ben Stiller Yes
```

I've tried with

```
df['Actor'].str.split(':',expand=True)
```

But it resulted the following:

```
23  Don Cheadle None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
24  Ben Stiller 2827.0  37  76.4    Meet the Fockers    279.3   Ben Stiller Yes
```

i.e It replaced the values into None.

Dataset I'm using is:

```
    Actor   Total Gross Number of Movies    Average per Movie   #1 Movie    Gross   Firstname   Lastname    Price
0   Harrison Ford   4871.7  41  118.8   Star Wars: The Force Awakens    936.7   Harrison    Ford    yes
1   Samuel Jackson  4772.8  69  69.2    The Avengers    623.4   Samuel  Jackson no
2   Morgan Freeman  4468.3  61  73.3    The Dark Knight 534.9   Morgan  Freeman Yes
3   Tom Hanks   4340.8  44  98.7    Toy Story 3 415 Tom Hanks   No
4   Robert Downey   3947.3  53  74.5    The Avengers    623.4   Robert  Downey  yes
5   Eddie Murphy    3810.4  38  100.3   Shrek 2 441.2   Eddie   Murphy  no
6   Tom Cruise  3587.2  36  99.6    War of the Worlds   234.3   Tom Cruise  yes
7   Johnny Depp 3368.6  45  74.9    Dead Mans Chest 423.3   Johnny  Depp    No
8   Michael Caine   3351.5  58  57.8    The Dark Knight 534.9   Michael Caine   NO
9   Scarlett Johansson  3341.2  37  90.3    The Avengers    623.4   Scarlett    Johansson   n0
10  Gary Oldman 3294    38  86.7    The Dark Knight 534.9   Gary    Oldman  No
11  Robin Williams  3279.3  49  66.9    Night at the Museum 250.9   Robin   Williams    no
12  Bruce Willis    3189.4  60  53.2    Sixth Sense 293.5   Bruce   Willis  no
13  Stellan Skarsgard   3175    43  73.8    The Avengers    623.4   Stellan Skarsgard   yes
14  Anthony Daniels 3162.9  7   451.8   Star Wars: The Force Awakens    936.7   Anthony Daniels no
15  Ian McKellen    3150.4  31  101.6   Return of the King  377.8   Ian McKellen    No
16  Will Smith  3149.1  24  131.2   Independence Day    306.2   Will    Smith   no
17  Stanley Tucci   3123.9  50  62.5    Catching Fire   424.7   Stanley Tucci   yes
18  Matt Damon  3107.3  39  79.7    The Martian 228.4   Matt    Damon   no
19  Robert DeNiro   3081.3  79  39  Meet the Fockers    279.3   Robert  DeNiro  No
20  Cameron Diaz    3031.7  34  89.2    Shrek 2 441.2   Cameron Diaz    No
21  Liam Neeson 2942.7  63  46.7    The Phantom Menace  -474.5  Liam    Neeson  No
22  Andy Serkis 2890.6  23  125.7   Star Wars: The Force Awakens    936.7   Andy    Serkis  Yes
23  Don Cheadle 2885.4  34  84.9    Avengers: Age of Ultron 459 Don Cheadle YEs
24  Ben Stiller:2827.0:37:76.4:Meet the Fockers:27...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: can you provide an MRE? post the data you are using

Comment: @ombk, posted the data I am using.

Comment: i think u should just apply the transsformation on ben stiller's row